# how to loop through items but display them in group of 6

Tags: php, loops

I have an array of 34 logos. I would like to display them but I want to make a slider and have 6 logos on each slides.

I have difficulties to create the loop. My code is in Php but it's the logic who matters here I think. Here what I have done so far. I miss the loop in the middle.

```
$number_of_slides = round($logo_array, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP);
    for($i ; $i <  $number_of_slides ; $i++):
       <div class="slide">
          ......
       </div>
    <?php endfor; ?>
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 3):

If you already have your array split it into [chunks](http://php.net/array_chunk):

```
$logo_array = [];
$chunks = array_chunk($logo_array, 6);  // 6 is a size of chunk
foreach ($chunks as $chunk) {
    // do dome stuff for each chunk, open some wrapper div or whatever

    foreach ($chunk as $logo) {
        // output current logo
    }

    // do dome stuff for each chunk, close some wrapper div or whatever
}
```

Comment: @Nina Between the `foreach`(s) insert `echo '<div class="slide">';` and before the last `}` insert `echo '</div>';`

Comment: With the ":" syntax, no need to echo

Comment: @Nina: ... but you should still use `?>` after the `:`. And the variable `$i` was never initialised in your script.

Comment: Why are you commenting __my__ answer?))))

Comment: Works like a charm ! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Sorry I was commented the comment of the echo thing. Your solution is great :)

Answer (score 0):

Or, if you want to do it in one loop, you could use some modulo logic:

```
$number_of_slides = 25;
$str='<div class="slide">';
for ($i=0 ; $i < $number_of_slides-1 ; $i++) {
 $str.= $logo_array[$i].($i%6==5?"</div>\n<div class=\"slide\">":' ');
} 
$str.=$logo_array[$i].'</div>';

echo $str;  // output the whole string
```

A simplified demo can be found here: http://rextester.com/DVMPR99965

Answer (score 0):

This not have any sense... your slider is in JS I presume? If it is, all logos would necessarily be into page and is your slider that will take care of the rest.

Some sliders have a specific verbose to separate the itens, others don't, just needing to set the max number of itens to be displayed into page.

What I would do? Well:

```
 <div class="slide">
 <?php
 foreach($logo_array as logo){
     echo "<img src='{$logo[src]}'>"; //or other tag pattern of your slider
 }
 ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes but each slide contains 6 logos, it's not a logo by slide

Comment: Slide will be your container. You put all your logos inside container and let the JS do the magic.

What are your js slider plugin?

Comment: Well, i looked you already found your solution, if you want other approach, i'm here

Comment: I think I know what you are talking about...the thing is it's a specific layout in the slide. Thanks anyway